# Eliminar objetos de un array, con valores de otro array

Tags: javascript

Tengo ese array de objetos que necesito filtrar para dejar solamente los objetos que tenga en su data, coincidencia con el array de permisos. Con esas funciones que ya tengo estoy logrando obtener los objetos que tienen data con un solo elemento en el array, no funciona cuando tiene mas de 1 elemento y tambien me falta aun para obtener los childrens, que no se como llegar a ellos y ponerlos en el mismo sitio o quitarlos, agradecería su ayuda. Muchas gracias!

```
permissions= ["create:users", "read:profile", "read:roles", "read:users", "update:users", "write:messages"] ;

const menuI=[
              {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                icon: 'home-outline',
                link: '/',
                home: true,
                children: undefined,
              },
              {
                title: 'Profile',
                icon: 'lock-outline',
                link: '/profile',
                children: undefined,
              },
              {
                title: 'Users',
                icon: 'person-outline',
                link: '/users',
                data:  ['read-user','create-user'],
                children: [
                  {
                    title: 'Users',
                    link: '/users',
                    data: 'read-user',
                  },
                  {
                    title: 'Create User',
                    link: '/edit-user',
                    data: 'create-user',
                  },           ],
                }
              ]


function hasExpectedPermissions(data) {
        console.log(data);
        let permissionsa= ["create:users", "read:profile", "read:roles", "read:users", "update:users", "write:messages"] ;
        return data.filter(function (data) {
          // Only return expected permissions that are NOT found in the permissions array
          return permissionsa.indexOf(data) === -1;
        }).length === 0; // If didn't find any MISSING permissions, we're good

      }

      function getAllowedPages(pages) {
        return pages.filter(function (page) {
          return !page.data
            || hasExpectedPermissions(page.data);
        }).map(pages) {
          if (pages.children) {
            pages.children = getAllowedPages(pages.children);
          }
          return pages;
        });
      }

      console.log("get",getAllowedPages(menuI));
```

Comment: Prueba con [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map) y guardalo en una nueva variable

Comment: me puedes oriantar un poco, no se como adaptarlo a lo que necesito, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a ver así de pronto:

```
const permissions = ["create:users", "read:profile", "read:roles", "read:users", "update:users", "write:messages"];

const menuI = [
  {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'home-outline',
    link: '/',
    home: true,
    children: undefined,
  },
  {
    title: 'Profile',
    icon: 'lock-outline',
    link: '/profile',
    children: undefined,
  },
  {
    title: 'Users',
    icon: 'person-outline',
    link: '/users',
    data: ['read:users', 'create:users'],
    enabled: false,
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Users',
        link: '/users',
        data: ['read:users'],
        enabled: false
      },
      {
        title: 'Create User',
        link: '/edit-user',
        data: ['create:users'],
        enabled: false
      }
    ]
  }
];



function hasExpectedPermissions(page) {
  // let permissionsa = ["create:users", "read:profile", "read:roles",  "update:users", "write:messages"]; // Users without /users
  // let permissionsa = ["read:users", "read:profile", "read:roles",  "update:users", "write:messages"]; // Users without /edit-user
  // let permissionsa = ["create:users", "read:users", "read:profile", "read:roles",  "update:users", "write:messages"]; // Users with all
  let permissionsa = ["read:profile", "read:roles",  "update:users", "write:messages"]; // No Users

  for(const data of page.data) {
    page.enabled = permissionsa.indexOf(data) > -1 || page.enabled;
  }

  return page.enabled;
}

function getAllowedPages(pages) {
  return pages.filter(function (page) {
    return (page.data === undefined) || (hasExpectedPermissions(page) === true);
  }).map(page => {
    if (page.children) {
      page.children = getAllowedPages(page.children);
    }
    return page;
  });
}

console.log("get", getAllowedPages(menuI));
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], editar y explicar tu aporte lo haría mas sencillo de comprender